# How to go back after running onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hidden" id="question-number-<?php echo $key+1; ?>">
Content question here
</div>

<button type="button" name="button" id="next-btn-<?php echo $quiz_question['id'];?>" onclick="showNextQuestion('<?php echo $key+2; ?>');">Next</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function showNextQuestion(next_question) {
    $('#question-number-'+(next_question-1)).hide();
    $('#question-number-'+next_question).show();
}
```

When I click the next button it displays the next question. I need to add a button to go back to the previous question.

Is there a way to do this just by reversing something in that function?

I tried it this way:

```
<button type="button" name="button" id="" onclick="showPrevQuestion('<?php echo $key+2; ?>');">Prev</button>

function showPrevQuestion(next_question) {
        $('#question-number-'+(next_question-2)).show();
        $('#question-number-'+next_question-1).hide();
}
```

The first part worked (`$('#question-number-'+(next_question-2)).show();`), it showed the previous question but did not hide the current question.

Comment: No, you'll have to write a showPreviousQuestion method

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to do this function, I am new to this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post your html for more clear but you may call below function to view previous question.

```
function showPrevQuestion(next_question) {
    $('#question-number-'+next_question).hide();
    $('#question-number-'+(next_question-1)).show();   
}

<button type="button" name="button" onclick="showPrevQuestion('<?php echo $key+1; ?>');">Prev</button>
```

Comment: I had already tried it that way, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post your html after Going to next answer.